Bricks self-evaluation: let's get critical!
You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!
Below you'll find a few questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?
Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.
Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

There were only 3 questions that qualified, hence the shortness of this evaluation.

How does a question qualify?

There's an algorithm that picks these questions, with various criteria. Only three made the cut. :(

Thanks for your input, everyone!

What's the best way to link two (or more) LEGO Power Functions (PF) train motors together?
What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

I think this was a good question, with a good answer - I just forgot to dig out the example I'd found to add some more colour to the answers, thanks for the nudge ;)

I agree that the question itself is good, but the fact there's only one answer with a meagre 3 votes (and it's not even accepted) doesn't scream "good answer" too me. (Plus, the guy who answered was obviously lazy - seriously, is it that hard to add pictures?). The fact the OP only connected twice after asking this question and hasn't been seen for a month makes me think we disappointed him.

There we go, I've added my answer, thanks for the reminder ;)

Is it possible to build a full-size house with Lego bricks?
What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

One of the first questions on the site. I'm not a fan of this particular question and very few people are qualified to speak on experience. A good answer should highlight the challenges of building a LEGO home, like the financial and structural aspects. Anyone searching 'Life size LEGO house' is more likely to come across the James May news articles anyway.

Agreed on that, it's quite unlikely anyone would want to do that seriously apart from the one experiment which is indeed easy to find on the net. On the other hand, the answer isn't too bad, even if the whole "would it make sense" part of the question isn't even answered.

I've added more details based on the show, to make it a more canonical answer.

NXC Saturation algorithm for limiting motors?
What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

I think the question is interesting, but it shows one of our limitations: we don't seem to have much experts on robotics subjects if they're a bit deep (there are a lot of questions with that same issue). The one answer isn't even really one, so I feel we're failing the asker here.
